# shouldChangeCharactersInRange is not being called.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have the method that has to be called to check mobile number range and other format. But this method is not being called :(

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    ProfileBasicCell *cell=[_tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    if (cell.txtMobile.text== textField && string.length>0) {
        NSString *newText=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if (newText.length<=15) {
            if (newText.length==4 || newText.length==8) {
               textField.text=[newText stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
               return NO;
             }
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }  
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: check if your textfield has the delegate set?

Comment: [cell.txtMobile setDelegate:<#(id<UITextFieldDelegate> _Nullable)#>];
what expression should I put here in in<<#(id<UITextFieldDelegate> _Nullable)#>
@deyanlai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did u set the delegate?

```
class yourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

}

self.yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set UITextFieldDelegate in your controller like this way

```
class yourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

then you need to give delegate in your UITextfield like this way

```
yourTextfield.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate. There are two ways :

> 1. Set it through storyboard

To set it through the Storyboard, right click you textfield, and drag `delegate` to `View Controller`

> 2. Set it programatically

UITextFieldDelegate add to view controller, and set delegate for your textfield. Something like this : `self.textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: Text fields do not have a data source I suppose.